# Holomorphic Euler characteristic of a pushforward

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, pushforward

It shouldn't be difficult to show that when $C$ is union of lines in generic position in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$, then its normalisation map $f:\tilde C \rightarrow C$ with $\tilde C$ being the disjoint union of corresponding lines induces an equality $\chi(\mathcal{O}_\tilde C)=\chi(f_*\mathcal{O}_\tilde C)$

> Is it true (the above equality of holomorphic Euler characteristic) in general for any normalisation map? What could be the conditions providing $\chi(\mathcal{O}_\tilde C)=\chi(f_*\mathcal{O}_\tilde C)$ or more general $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)=\chi(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)$ with $f:X\rightarrow Y$ ?

I know that when $f:Z\rightarrow X$ is a closed embedding than all cohomologies for $\mathcal{O}_Z$ and $f_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ coincide, in particular the holomorphic euler characteristics are the same.

Comment: I think it's true for every normalization map. In fact, every normalization is an affine morphism, and for an affine morphism of noetherian separated schemes $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ in $X$, $H^i(X, \mathcal{F}) = H^i(Y, f_*\mathcal{F})$ for every $i \geq 0$ (this is exercise III.4.1 of Hartshorne). So your equality is true for all affine morphisms. More generally, I guess you don't want fibres to have higher cohomology (but I'm only guessing)

Comment: @JaneDoé good comment, and I think it would be even better as an answer.

Comment: @JaneDoé I'm not sure if you were claiming that for $f:X\to Y$ to have $R^i f_\ast\mathcal{F}$ for $i>0$ to be zero (which is what you want for $H^j(X,\mathcal{F})=H^j(Y,f_\ast\mathcal{F})$ to hold) that it's sufficient to have $ H^i(X_y,\mathcal{F}_y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$ and $i>0$. This is not the case. For example, if $f:(\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\})\to \mathbb{A}^2$ is the natural inclusion and $\mathcal{F}$ is the structure sheaf.

Comment: @JaneDoé I answered the question. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Of course not, and it looks like I have something to learn from your answer as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\an}{\mathrm{an}}$As  Jane Doé commented above, the key thing is the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $f:X\to Y$ be an affine morphism of schemes. Then, for any quasi-coherent $\mathcal{F}$ we have that there is a natural isomorphism $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\cong H^i(Y,f_\ast\mathcal{F})$ for all $i\geqslant 0$.

*Proof:* The Leray spectral sequence for $f$ shows us that we have a spectral sequence

$$E^{p,q}_2=H^p(Y,R^q f_\ast\mathcal{F})\implies H^{p+q}(X,\mathcal{F})$$

But, note that for all $q>0$ we have that $R^q f_\ast\mathcal{F}=0$. Indeed, to show this it suffices to show that for all $y\in Y$ there exists some affine open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ such that $(R^qf_\ast\mathcal{F})\mid_U=0$. But, take $U$ to be affine. Then, as is well-known $(R^qf_\ast\mathcal{F})\mid_U\cong \widetilde{H^q(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{F})}$. Since $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine, by assumption, this is zero by Serre's affineness criterion. Clearly then the spectral sequence collapses on the second page and we get the desired result. $\blacksquare$

Your literal question is then answered by the fact that normalization morphisms are affine by construction--you literally normalized affine open by affine open.

---

We actually have the following well-known, but surprisingly difficult result:

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a finite type $k$-scheme. Then, the normalization map $\nu:X'\to X$ is finite.

*Proof:* If you want the most general version you can combine [Tag035S](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035S) and [Tag0335](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0335). In Vakil this is 9.7.3, but he defers to Eisenbud's book for a proof. $\blacksquare$

The reason that this might be of interest to you is the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite morphism of schemes (resp. finite morphism of algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$). Then, for any sheaf of abelian groups $\mathcal{F}$ on the etale site of $X$ (resp. any sheaf of abelian groups on $X^\mathrm{an}$, the analytification of $X$) we have a natural isomorphism of cohomology groups $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\cong H^i(Y,f_\ast\mathcal{F})$ (resp. $H^i(X^\mathrm{an},\mathcal{F}^\mathrm{an})\cong H^i(Y^\mathrm{an},f^\mathrm{an}_\ast\mathcal{F}^\mathrm{an})$).

*Proof:* By the same Leray spectral sequence argument, it suffices to show that for $q>0$ we have that $R^q f_\ast\mathcal{F}=0$ and $R^q f^\mathrm{an}_\ast\mathcal{F}^\an=0$.

The second case is easier since we have the simpler [Hausdorff version of proper base change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_change_theorems#Proper_base_change) which tells us that (since $X^\an$ and $Y^\an$ are Hausdorff, $Y^\an$ locally compact, and $f^\an$ universally closed since $f$ is proper) that:

$$(R^q f^\an_\ast\mathcal{F}^\an)_y=H^q(f^{-1}(y),\mathcal{F}^\an)=0$$

where this last equality holds since $f^{-1}(y)$ is a finite discrete set of points.

The first case requires more care. What's true in general is that for any geometric point $\overline{y}$ of $Y$ we have that

$$(R^q f_\ast \mathcal{F})_\overline{y}\cong H^q(X_{(\overline{y})},\mathcal{F})$$

where $X_{(\overline{y})}$ is the so-called *Milnor fiber* $X\times_Y \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,\overline{y}})$ where $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\overline{y}}$ is the local ring at $\overline{y}$ in the etale topology (i.e. its the strict Henselization of $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ where $y$ is the underlying point of $\overline{y}$). The point though is that since $f$ is finite we have that $X_{(\overline{y})}\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,\overline{y}})$ is finite, which means that $X_{(\overline{y})}$ is a finite disjoint union of spectra of strictly Henselian local rings, and thus has trivial etale cohomology. $\blacksquare$

The point of this is that you can now take $\mathcal{F}$ to be *any* sheaf on the etale site of $X$ or, if $X$ is over $\mathbb{C}$, any sheaf on $X^\an$, not just quasi-coherent ones if your map is finite (e.g. a normalization map).

Two examples:

- You can take $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{G}_m$ which can be used to to compute the Picard group of non-normal varieties in terms of their normalizations (e.g. see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196846/kernel-of-pullback-map-of-line-bundles/3196875#3196875)).
- You can compute $H^i(X,\underline{R})$ where $X$ is the projective cuspidal cubic over an algebraically closed fiekd $k$) and $R$ is any finite ring (this cohomology is etale cohomology). Namely, we have that the normalization of $X$ is $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ and so by the above we know that $H^i(\mathbb{P}^1_k,\underline{R})\cong H^i(X,\nu_\ast\underline{R})$ where $\nu$ is the normalization map. But, since $\nu$ is a universal homeomorphism we have that $\nu_\ast\underline{R}=\underline{R}$ which tells you that $H^i(\mathbb{P}^1_k,\underline{R})\cong H^i(X,\underline{R})$.
- You can take $\mathcal{F}=\underline{R}$, for any ring $R$, on $X^\mathrm{an}$ (assuming that $X$ is finite type over $\mathbb{C}$) to see that 
  $$H^i_\mathrm{sing}(X^\mathrm{an},R)\cong H^i(Y^\mathrm{an},f^\an_\ast\underline{R})$$
  which comes up surprisingly often.

**NB:** The above second example is somewhat perverse. Namely, any universal homeomorphism gives an equivalece of etale sites (e.g. see [Tag04DY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DY)). This can be used to alternatively compute the result in the second bullet, but this computation is of a different nature, in some sense, than the one presented here.

---

The last thing I wanted to point out was that, as mentioned in the comments, it is not good enough in general that $H^q(f^{-1}(y),\mathcal{F})=0$ for $q>0$ to imply that we have an isomorphism of cohomology groups $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\cong H^i(Y,f_\ast\mathcal{F})$.

For example, let $j$ be the inclusion of $X=\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\}$ into $Y=\mathbb{A}^2$. Let us note that $j^{-1}(y)$ is either empty, or a point, for all $y\in Y$ and so evidently $H^q(j^{-1}(Y),\mathcal{F})=0$ for all $q>0$. That said, we claim that it's not necessarily true that $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\cong H^i(Y,j_\ast\mathcal{F})$.

Indeed, we claim that $j_\ast\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$. We have a natural map $\mathcal{O}_X\to j_\ast\mathcal{O}_Y$ coming from restriction. This is actually an isomorphism by algebraic Hartog's lemma (e.g. see Theorem 6.45 of Gortz and Wedhorn). Note then that

$$\dim_k H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\dim_k H^1(\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\}})=\infty$$

but

$$H^1(Y,j_\ast\mathcal{O}_X)=H^1(\mathbb{A}^2,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2})=0$$

and so evidently the two are not isomorphic.

The issue is that $j$ is not affine, of course!

Even if you try this in the analytic category, where it seemed like all you needed was quasi-finiteness, you notice that we applied 'Hausdorff proper base change` and thus actually need properness. But, as ZMT tells us, quasi-finite and proper implies finite (and thus affine) which our map is not! In short, our map is not proper.